# How to access/change the content of a button from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want a certain function to execute from a command depending on the content of the button. As of now I have two buttons. [DesignImg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKvI6.png) When connect is clicked I need to change it to "Disconnect". How do I access the content of the button from my view model.

Here is my viewModel where I will connect/disconnect:

```
namespace firstApp
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public TcpClient client = null;
        public ICommand MyCommand { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            MyCommand = new Command(ExecuteMethod, canExecuteMethod);
        }

        private bool canExecuteMethod(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void ExecuteMethod(object parameter)
        {
            //if client is not connected do this... id client is connected then close client.
            try
            {
                // Create a TcpClient.
                // Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer
                // connected to the same address as specified by the server, port
                // combination.
                Int32 port = 8000;
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", port);

            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
```

And here is the view model of my send:

```
namespace firstApp
{
    public class SendViewModel: ViewModel
    {
        public ICommand MySendCommand { get; set; }

        public SendViewModel()
        {
            MyCommand = new Command(ExecuteMethod, canExecuteMethod);
        }

        private bool canExecuteMethod(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void ExecuteSendMethod(object parameter)
        {
            if (client.Connected)
            {
                Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello");

                // Get a client stream for reading and writing.
                //  Stream stream = client.GetStream();

                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                // Send the message to the connected TcpServer.
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                //ChatScreentextBox.AppendText(TextToSend);//probably done need it here
                                                           //worker1.RunWorkerAsync();///gets to here
            }
            else
            {
                //ChatScreentextBox.AppendText("There is no connection");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just use an if statement in your command. And style trigger in your XAML. style trigger will change the text of the button and a bool in the view model can tell you if you are connected or not. Or at least that is a way you could get the desired results.

Comment: Like if button.content = "Connect" do this function? if so how do I access that information if I am in a viewModel. I am new to wpf so I may be misunderstanding your answer

Comment: I was thinking that you have a variable that is something like IsConnected. That when you click the button is changed to be its inverse. Then you have a style trigger on your button that changes its name based on the bool. Your command then just checks the bool variable and does one or the other based on it.

Answer (score 2):

C#

```
//This variable needs to be usable in XAML fyi
private bool IsConnected = false;

// Your command method
private void ChangeConnectionStatus()
{
  if (IsConnected)
  {
    IsConnected = false;
    //call method for connecting bellow
  }
  else
  {
    IsConnected = true;
    //call method for disconnecting bellow
  }
}
```

XAML

```
                     <Button Command="{Binding ChangeConnectionStatus}">
                        <Button.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Button">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsConnected}" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Conected" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsConnected}" Value="false">
                                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Disconected" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Style>
                    </Button>
```

Not copy and pasteable code but should give you an idea of how to do it.

Also in the ViewModel usually people try to avoid editing the view that's why the DataTrigger is generally a better way because it keeps them separated.

Answer (score 0):

Add a ViewModel property and bind it to the button text. Then you can change the button text to something else easily. Note that your ViewModel will need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and add the appropriate event and event-raising method.

In ViewModel (assumes `INotifyPropertyChanged` is implemented):

```cs
private string _connectButtonText = "Connect"; // set initial value here or in the constructor
public string ConnectButtonText { get => _connectButtonText; set => { _connectButtonText = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ConnectButtonText)); }
```

In XAML (assumes your page's `DataContext` is set to your ViewModel):

```xml
<Button Text={Binding ConnectButtonText} ... />
```

To change the button text, in your ViewModel:

```cs
public void ExecuteSendMethod(object parameter)
{
    ...

    ConnectButtonText = "Disconnect";

    ...
}
```